# 17.10 Error were encountered while processing python-olefile

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg

Fairly new install of 17.10.  At some point I apparently botched something, because I now get a dpkg error while processing python-olefile.

> Setting up python-olefile (0.44-1) ...
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)
>   dpkg: error processing package python-olefile (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
>   Setting up python-olefile (0.44-1) ...
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)
>   dpkg: error processing package python-olefile (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139

I think I first noticed it when installing Kodi from the software center, but the actual problem may have came from an operation prior to that and I didn't notice.

I've tried running some of various package manager commands to try to clean it up but haven't had any success

```
sudo dpkg --configure python-olefile
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt remove python-olefile
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt install python-olefile -f
sudo dpkg -r python-olefile
```

I've also run dpkg --audit and got the following result:

> The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
>   configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
>   dpkg --configure  or the configure menu option in dselect:
>    python-olefile       Python module to read/write MS OLE2 files

There were a few PPAs that have been added, but disabling them and trying to fix/finish the install doesn't seem to help so I don't know that they are the culprit.  If there's any further detail I can provide that might help diagnose this, I'll try to provide.